# MYSQL Several questions scripts and lack of statements able to use, insert only when not exist

Tags: mysql

30 years in microsoft land I am using mysql for my own project.  I am trying to figure out the following:
It seems commands you can use in a stored procedure as not usable in a generic script.

**Question #1**
How do people write initialization scripts or update scripts for creating the database or for migrating changes to production.  Meaning I do IF NOT EXISTS doing any action where I create something or insert something.

**Question #2**
IF NOT EXISTS INSERT.  It has a unique id (not known at time inserting), the table as created date for the row.  Below can be written in a stored procedure but not in a generic script because it doesn't recognize the IF statement.
 `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM permissions_groups WHERE group_name='Billing Admin') THEN  INSERT INTO permission_groups (group_id ,company_id ,group_name,notes,date_created,active,deleted) VALUES (0, 0,'Billing Admin', 'this groups represents those who do the accounting portion of administrator', NOW(), 1, 0); END IF;`

**Question #1 Solutions**? Only think I can think of is everything has to be written in stored proc.  which doesn't make sense when establishing a db or updating the schemas/data in them.  What am I missing?

**Questions #2 Solutions I have seen for not knowing primary key.**

I always doubt when something seams hokey but the stuff I found for the insert statement basically stated the following solutions. the data I saw said the ignore should work but it doesn't.  I prefer ignore it is cleaner to me. Anything I am missing?

**Questions #2 - Solutions #1 - This works**
`INSERT INTO permission_groups (group_id ,company_id ,group_name,notes,date_created,active,deleted) SELECT 0, 0,'Billing Admin', 'this groups represents those who do the accounting portion of administrator', NOW(), 1, 0 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM permissions_groups WHERE group_name='Billing Admin')`

**Questions #2 - SOLUTION #2 - this does *not* work keeps inserting.**

my primary key is autoincrement id
`INSERT IGNORE INTO permission_groups (company_id ,group_name,notes,active,deleted) VALUES (0,'Billing Admin', 'this groups represents those who do the accounting portion of administrator', 1, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the `IF/THEN/ELSE` statement is not supported outside of stored routines. Nor are any of the compound statements. MySQL supports these only in stored routines. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html

> This section describes the syntax for the `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and other statements **that can be used in the body of stored programs...**

(my emphasis)

The `INSERT IGNORE` example you show inserts in your case because you must not have defined a constraint that rejects duplicate group names.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE permission_groups ADD UNIQUE KEY (group_name);
```

Once you define such a constraint, if you try to insert a row with a group_name that already exists in the table, you get an error, or else INSERT IGNORE and get no error. Either way, no row is inserted.

As for running CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE to initialize or change metadata, this falls into a broad category of schema change management tools. There are many free, open source tools to help with this. Many of them have gained popularity in specific programming language communities, because they are designed to integrate with projects written in a specific language. For example SQLAlchemy for Python, LiquiBase for Java, Rails Migrations for Ruby, etc.

There are also some cool helper tools that are independent of programming language, for example [Skeema](https://www.skeema.io/).

I generally recommend avoiding stored procedures in MySQL for any task. This might not make sense given your experience in Microsoft-land, but you should be aware that MySQL's implementation of stored procedures supports no compiler, no packages or modules, no debugger, no standard library of helper procedures, no atomic deployment, etc. I predict you will just get annoyed every day at the things MySQL's procedures cannot do.

Instead, pick your favorite scripting language and get used to writing your own tools in that language. A popular language for this sort of work is Python, but some people prefer Go, Ruby, Lua, PHP, or Node.js. I've even written scripts in Bash.

Anything you can do in a stored procedure is easier to develop and maintain in virtually any client programming language.

Comment: Thanks Bill for answering so greatly appreactiated!